# Java Inheritance Array

Tags: java

```
    class Employee extends Person {
    
    private double salary;
    private int departmentId;
    
    public void setSalary(double s) {
        this.salary = s;
    }
    
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    
    public void setDepartmentId(int i) {
        this.departmentId = i;
    }
    
    public int getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }
}
```

Department class

```
class Department extends Employee {
    private String[] department[];
    
    public String[][] getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
```

What I was trying is to display something like if the user input 1 the allocated 1 on array will print something. But every time i use this syntax

```
Employee[] e1 = new Employee[6];
e1[1] = "asd";
```

Please help. i kinda get the error Type Mismatch: Cannot convert String to employee

Comment: You need to assign Employee instance to e1[1] not a String.

Comment: Yea but what I want is to store a string in my array

Comment: Then you need to use a `String[]`, Java can't magically convert types

Comment: Your class structure does not make sense. We read "extends" as "is a": then you write that a Department is an Employee. I guess you jumped too far forward on your programming learning curve. Be patient and follow some programming-basics course or tutorial step-by-step.

Comment: I just want to use that getDepartment thingy, because I think that is what my professor wants us to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i understand what you try to do.
First of all `Department` should not extend `Employee`. That would only make sence, if your apartment was some kind of Employee. Secondly your department array is an array of arrays, because you are using the square brackets 2 times. If you just make it a usual array you can then use it to save all the names of the departments. Now you only need a way to set these departments, and a cosntructor to make an object of the class, and ready is your Department class:

```
class Department {
    private String[] department;
    
    public Department() { }

    public String[] getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String[] newDepartment) {
        department = newDepartment;
    }
}
```

Your Employee class should also get a constructor, so you can make an object of the class:

```
public Employee() { }
```

Now you need to make an String Array with all departments in it and pass it to your class. Then you can use the index of these deparments as the departmentId in employee:

```
String[] departmentNames = new String[6];
Department departmentManager = new Department();
Employee e1 = new Employee();

departmentNames[0] = "xyz";
departmentNames[1] = "asd";
//...

departmentManager.setDepartment(departmentNames);

e1.setDepartmentId(1);
```

Now the `departmentId` in `employee` shows which entry of the array in department is his department and you can show it by calling:

```
System.out.println(departmentManager.getDepartment()[e1.getDepartmentId()]);
```